# cmake add_custom_target preserve directory

Tags: cmake

Imagine the following lines in a CMakeFiles.txt:

```
add_custom_target( target
          cd bin
          COMMAND echo "test" > README
)
```

`make target` will not work as expected, as it will not modify the file `bin/README` but rather the file `./README`. I found out that, in order to make CMake modify `bin/README`, I have to write

`COMMAND cd bin && echo "test" > README`

which is time consuming and blows the CMakeLists up when used multiple times. I want a behavior that is much like the behaviour of shell scripts. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` directive:

```
add_custom_target( target
      COMMAND echo "test" > README
      WORKING_DIRECTORY bin
)
```

**EDIT**: Reversed COMMAND and WORKING_DIRECTORY order

Comment: I tried this, however that strangely fails if there are multiple COMMANDs. The working directory seems to be reset for the all but the first command, moreover multiple echo statements don't work. Strange.

Comment: Actually, I wrote it wrong.  Commands should be before the WORKING_DIRECTORY directive.  Try reversing the order.