# Add custom target (make) to CLion with custom binary path and custom working directory

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a make file that builds a binary, but the binary should be created in specific place and should be run from specific working directory.

I am working on integration of this make command into CLion project.

When I add custom target [(see this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918459/using-local-makefile-for-clion-instead-of-cmake#27871173) the configuration from the CLion point of view is incorrect because it doesn't have binary path and working directory path.

How can I make it see the proper executable and working directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir)

Comment: The second part of your question - specifying working directory for custom target - is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364867/cmake-add-custom-target-preserve-directory.